# SQL Server , restrict UNPIVOT to order columns automatically

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot, unpivot

I have a table with data in one row:

```
Account | OrderID   | OrderName          | Priority | Fasting   |AssignedTo       |ResultsTo    |Location
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12345   | REQ123456 | Lipid Panel (1.2)  |Routine   | Yes       |Fast, Brook      |Nurse Group  |Fisher Rd, Woodbridge, NV
```

Now I want to UNPIVOT the data to show the user in the following form:

```
GROUPCOL    | LABEL       | VALUE
-------------------------------------------------
General     | Account     | 12345
General     | OrderID     | REQ123456
General     | OrderName   | Lipid Panel (1.2)
General     | Priority    | Routine    
General     | Fasting     | Yes        
Result      | ResultsTo   | Nurse Group
Result      | AssignedTo  | Fast, Brook
Result      | Location    | Fisher Rd, Woodbridge, NV
```

I am struggling to find the solution that will restrict UNPIVOT to sort the columns by default. I want to order the columns my way. Here is the query:

```
SELECT  'General' GROUPCOL, LABEL, VALUE
FROM TESTPIVOT
UNPIVOT (
    VALUE FOR LABEL IN (Account, OrderID, OrderName, Priority, Fasting)
) AS UNPVT
UNION
SELECT  'Result' GROUPCOL, LABEL, VALUE
FROM TESTPIVOT
UNPIVOT (
    VALUE FOR LABEL IN (AssignedTo, ResultsTo, Location)
) AS UNPVT
```

The output is:

```
GROUPCOL    | LABEL       | VALUE
-------------------------------------------------
General     | Account     | 12345
General     | Fasting     | Yes        
General     | OrderID     | REQ123456
General     | OrderName   | Lipid Panel (1.2)
General     | Priority    | Routine    
Result      | AssignedTo  | Fast, Brook
Result      | Location    | Fisher Rd, Woodbridge, NV 
Result      | ResultsTo   | Nurse Group
```

I thought, if somehow I have a order column associated with the columns then I can order it at the end as desired (that way, I can change the order as per the requirement).

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using??

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using SQL Server 2008, then you can use `CROSS APPLY` and `VALUES` to UNPIVOT data.  Using this will allow you to create a column for Sorting Order:

```
select c.GroupCol, c.Label, c.Value
from testpivot
cross apply
(
  values
  ('General', 'Account', Account, 1),
  ('General', 'OrderID', OrderID, 2),
  ('General', 'OrderName', OrderName, 3),
  ('General', 'Priority', Priority, 4),
  ('General', 'Fasting', Fasting, 5),
  ('Result', 'ResultsTo', ResultsTo, 6),
  ('Result', 'AssignedTo', AssignedTo, 7),
  ('Result', 'Location', Location, 8)
) c (GroupCol, Label, Value, SortOrder)
order by sortorder;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3171b/4)

Comment: it is a great solution. I didn't know the versatility of CROSS APPLY. This seems to be a better solution where you can specify your order explicitly. I think I don't even need the sort order column unless, I give user an ability to change the sort order. Excellent!